# No suitable method found to override?

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error

```
 Dev_xsc_Build.BigEndianBinaryReader.ReadInt16()': no suitable method found to override
```

But I'm not sure where I am going wrong with

```
public override short ReadInt16()
    {
        byte[] byteBuffer = base.ReadBytes(2);
        return (short)((byteBuffer[0] << 8) | byteBuffer[1]);
    }
```

Any help please?

Comment: What happens if you remove the override keyword?

Comment: What is the declaration of the method you are trying to override?

Comment: What is the type of `Dev_xsc_Build.BigEndianBinaryReader` and what is the base type? If it is derived from `BinaryReader` it should be working.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying to override a virtual method:   `public **override** short ReadInt16()`.  This requires you to be inheriting from a class that contains a virtual method that matches that declaration.

In your case, the base class does not provide a virtual method that matches.  You should be able to just remove the `override` keyword:

```
public short ReadInt16()
{
    byte[] byteBuffer = base.ReadBytes(2);
    return (short)((byteBuffer[0] << 8) | byteBuffer[1]);
}
```

Comment: Should he add the `new` keyword to hide the existing definition?

Comment: @Harrison Not necessary. without `new` also it will shadow the base class `method`. `new` keyword is just to supress the warning

Comment: @Harrison I suspect there is no existing definition - If there was, there'd probably be no reason to override it at all...

Comment: Assuming the base class is [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.BinaryReader.aspx), ReadInt16 actually should be a virtual method.

Comment: @DanBryant In which case, there wouldn't have been this error in the first place, which is why I wasn't making that assumption...

Comment: Thanks figured it out